# How can I detect the availability of sp_addextendedproperty on sql server

Tags: sql-server

How can I find out if `sp_addextendedproperty` is available before trying to use it in a sql script?

I gather it's not available on Azure.

(I'm working on [this bug](https://github.com/timabell/ef-enum-to-lookup/issues/28), if you're interested).

Comment: Wouldn't TRY/CATCH work?

Comment: Also you say `I don't want to just detect that it is azure in case microsft add/remove this proc from various versions of sql server in the future.` Why not just *not* use extended properties in the first place?

Answer (score 4):

Use OBJECT_ID to see of the object exists.  The function will return NULL if not:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'sp_addextendedproperty', 'P') IS NOT NULL
    EXEC sp_addextendedproperty ...
```